# JQuery UI datepicker (validation issue)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery UI datepicker, I added date validation in my datepicker input field, this is my `javascript` code for datepicker ('**start_date**' is the **id** of my datepicker input field):

```
    $('#my-form').validate({
                rules: {
                    start_date: {
                        required: true

                    }

                },
                messages: {
                    start_date: 'Please enter a valid date (yyyy-mm-dd)'

                }
            }); 

$("#start_date").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: noTheseDays,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {alert(dateText)}});
```

my datepicker input field in **html**:

```
<form id="my-form" method="post">
   ...
    <input class="start_date_field" id="start_date" size="30" type="text" />
   <input id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="Get it" /> 
</form>
```

The problem is, if I add the **validation code** in **javascript**, the datepicker calendar is **not** showing when mouse click in the datepicker (start_date) input field. **If I remove the validation, the calendar shows**. Why??

The other problem is the validation **error message does not show**, if the datepicker input field is empty and I submit the form, an **error page is showing instead**.....

Answer (score 2):

You're missing input `name` attribute.
`validate` works with input names, not ids.
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/FBBxW/